# How to ignore profile selection banner (shell/plink)

Tags: shell, plink

I should run shell profile first for some reason and then need to get remote OS command results like below.

However, if there is a 'select' feature in the profile, the `plink` is stuck.
Is there any way to ignore this 'selection'?

```
plink -ssh -l username -pw passwd 192.168.0.5 " . ~/.profile 2> /dev/null; ls; "

Selection enter a number

1. Your choice = one
2. Your choice = two
3. Your choice = three
Please enter your choice:
```

Comment: Don't put interactive stuff in your `.profile`; it screws things up.  Or "Doctor, Doctor, it hurts when I put interactive stuff in my `.profile`"…

Comment: Unsure if `plink` allows for it, but a common approach would be to redirect input from `/dev/null`.  On Windows, of course, there may perhaps be no such thing as a readable `nul:` device?

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, you'll want to drop the `~/` prefix, which is not portable to traditional `sh`.

Comment: I think I should try to remove the profile selection part. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's a server-side problem, not to be solved on a client-side.

You need to move the interactive stuff away from the `.profile` to an appropriate place (the `.bashrc` for the bash shell).